# How to set default value for KendoDropDownTreeView

Tags: kendo-ui

i am using kendodropdownTreeview for display treeview in dropdownlist

```
var dropDownTreeView = $("#dropDownTreeView").kendoExtDropDownTreeView({
treeview: {
    dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data: [
            {
                text: "Furniture", items: [
                  { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
                  { text: "Sofas" },
                  { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: "Decor", items: [
                  { text: "Bed Linen" },
                  { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
                  { text: "Carpets" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    })
}}).data("kendoExtDropDownTreeView");
```

i want to set default selected value 'Decor' , how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no kendoExtDropDownTreeView component, but I beleive you are talking about the TreeView. if this is the case, then this seems to be working:

http://dojo.telerik.com/uVAYU